# GeoDjango - Which tables should inherit from django.contrib.gis.db.models?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, gis, geodjango

I've just followed the tutorial to install GeoDjango for Django 1.9 and I'm trying to write my user models, but I'm not sure which tables should inherit from `django.contrib.gis.db.models` rather than the regular `django.db.models`.

I'm making a `Customer` table which has a PointField for their location, and a table that inherits from customer named `Traveller`. I also have a third table `Equipment` which has a foreign key to `Traveller`.

Is my inheritance right? Is there a better way to do it?

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.db import models

class Customer(gis_models.Model):
    user = gis_models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    location = gis_models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gis_location = gis_models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
            geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    name = gis_models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Traveller(Customer):
    will_travel = gis_models.NullBooleanField()

class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'Traveller', 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code from `django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py`

```
from django.db.models import *  # NOQA isort:skip
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import (  # NOQA
    GeometryCollectionField, GeometryField, LineStringField,
    MultiLineStringField, MultiPointField, MultiPolygonField, PointField,
    PolygonField, RasterField,
)
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.manager import GeoManager  # NOQA
```

gis module imports all models defined in django, and adds some of its own.

So you can safely inherit all your models from the gis models. It's the same thing.